# Java Socket Programming LAN Messenger

Tags: java, sockets, networking, lan, ports

I am working on Lan Messenger, how can I check if somebody else's system has LAN plugged in? 
Means, is that person Online?

Also, our hostel has LAN, and I've tried running the client server program a lot many times, but it runs fine on my system (2 clients on the same machine as server) but it doesn't run when server and client are on different machines.
The code is perfectly fine.
What could be the reason? Any special Firewall settings to be changed for allowing packets?

Comment: 1) LAN is not online 2) Check if his/her IP address is up

Comment: There are a lot of ways to do that.
For correct answer, you should describe your architecture in more details. It's impossible to answer your question without information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm creating a chat server using sockets right now and the way I'm doing it is I have every user query the server about every 20-30 seconds.  The server keeps track of the last time a user "refreshed" itself.  If a user's gone a certain time period or more without doing so, then the server tells anyone trying to contact this user that they are offline.

Here is a VERY good reference to work off of.  Take a look at the Server folder for the server-side and the src folder for the client-side:
https://code.google.com/p/simple-android-instant-messaging-application/source/browse/trunk/#trunk%2FServer%253Fstate%253Dclosed

If you only want to communicate within a LAN, then the socket implementatation in that link is defininitely what you want.  If you want to communicate globally( a user in 1 LAN to a user in some other LAN ) then you'll want to redesign it a little so that your server socket is actually on some server accepting client connections.  The current implementation creates a server socket within each client and accepts connections from other clients trying to communicate with it.  This design breaks due to NAT routers (for reasons I'd rather not explain unless you really want to know).

Comment: I got it. Thanks a lot. Sorry I don't have enough reputations to upvote your answer.

Comment: Hey, I'm facing a problem. A list of all the clients who connected is available at the server, is there any way that it can be sent to the client?

Comment: If everyone is querying the database every 20-30 seconds for users they care about, that information of whether they're online or not should be returned to them in the query's result.  The clients are requesting this info from the server every 30 seconds.  Does that make sense?